# How to fix error in identifying element using xpath for SAP Fiori UI

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm writing a selenium script for identifying an element and send keys to it for a SAP interface.

This for a SAP Fiori UI application.

Even though the xpath I have identified is unique when i run the code in chrome its not identifying the element.

Below is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
    String baseURL = "https://mercury.abc.net/default.aspx";

    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "C:\\Users\\abcde\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\Selenium 
     Practice\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

     // launch Chrome and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseURL);

    WebElement MyTimesheetButton = 
    driver.findElement(By.id("Tile_WPQ8_8_7"));
    MyTimesheetButton.click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//* 
    [@id=\"WD027B\"]"))); 

    WebElement Engagement =  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"WD027B\"]"));
    Engagement.sendKeys("test");

    //close Chrome
    driver.close();

}
```

I should get expected result as element identified and data keyed in to the element but I'm getting actual result as below :

```
Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //*[@id="WD027B"]
```

HTML:

```html
<iframe role="main" frameborder="0" title="The title of the hosted application within the canvas area: My Timesheet" '="" src="/nwbc/ZEP3_FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR/?sap-client=200&amp;sap-language=EN&amp;sap-nwbc-node=page_collection&amp;sap-nwbc-version_hash=392D742742D08304E969040C8A992A95&amp;sap-theme=zcorbu" id="iFrameId_1550067729776" name="iFrameId_1550067729776" style="display: block; width: 1036px; height: 641px;">Your&#x20;browser&#x20;is&#x20;currently&#x20;configured&#x20;not&#x20;to&#x20;display&#x20;inline&#x20;

<table id="WD027B-r" class="lsTblEdf3Whl lsField--table"> <tbody> <tr> <td class="lsTblEdf3Td urBorderBox" style="vertical-align:top;"><input id="WD027B" ct="CBS" lsdata="{0:'WD027B',5:'FREETEXT',7:'WD027C',14:true,20:40,25:'CLIENT_SERVER_PREFIX',26:'F4LOOKUP',30:true,32:40,34:true,35:'VALUE1'}" class="lsTblEdf3 urBorderBox urEdf2TxtHv" value="" role="combobox" name="WD027B" style="vertical-align:top;"> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Anything specific that's not there in the above code snippet ?

Comment: I mean you have provided ID looks like it’s a random value.Can you try with some other attribute.However that’s why I have asked for the html.So that OP can identify which you are unable to ATM.

Comment: Is your 'table' element inside a frame/iframe element?

Comment: Yes it is inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath It should work.

```
 WebElement Engagement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='WD027B-r']/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='WD027B']"));
    Engagement.sendKeys("test");
```

Please let me know if this work for you.

Comment: It did not work :( it still say's cannot locate element

Comment: can you please check is webtable inside any frame or not?

Answer (score 0):

As the element is within an `<iframe>` and a *dynamic* element so you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='iFrameId_'][src*='FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR']")));
  WebElement Engagement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("table.lsField--table td.urBorderBox>input.urBorderBox[ct='CBS']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'iFrameId_')][contains(@src, 'FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR')]")));
  WebElement Engagement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'lsField--table')]//td[contains(@class, 'urBorderBox')]/input[contains(@class, 'urBorderBox') and @ct='CBS']")));
  ```

Comment: Tried the xpath, when I give the xpath on developers tool it is identifying as unique xpath but when I put it in code and execute , it still says cannot locate the "Cannot locate an element using By.xpath:" .

Comment: @Komali Great news. So our locator is correct. Now inspect the HTML through the `inspector` and look out if the element is within a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`. If so you have to switch to the desired frame.

Comment: Yes, it is within an iframe. How do i include that in my xpath? Pardon my ignorance im new to selenium automation

Comment: Checkout my update answer to find the code to switch to the desired iframe before finding the element. I have put a `placeholder` for _class_ and _id_ attribute.

Comment: I have updated html snippet with the iframe in the question

Comment: I am getting "Cannot resolve Timespan" error in the code

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //iframe[starts-with(@id, 'iFrameId_') and contains(@title, 'Timesheet')][contains(@src, 'FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR')]

Comment: Can you copy the HTML starting from the `<iframe>` tag till the webelement and update the question?

Comment: Hmmm, factually you used half of my idea that is the _xpath_ path and discarded the _WebDriverWait_ path. Thats why you see the error. try to just copy and paste my code.

Comment: Actually, I have used the whole script 

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'iFrameId_') and contains(@title, 'Timesheet')][contains(@src, 'FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR')]")));
WebElement Engagement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'lsField--table')]//td[contains(@class, 'urBorderBox')]/input[contains(@class, 'urBorderBox') and @ct='CBS']")));

Comment: gimme a moment please

Comment: and I am not able to copy all the code from <iframe> to the element as the html content is huge

Comment: Hmmm, with _WebDriverWait_ you won't see `Cannot locate an element using By.xpath` error anyway. You would see a _timeout_ exception, madam

Comment: Yes, I have that error too
Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.xpath: //iframe[starts-with(@id, 'iFrameId_') and contains(@title, 'Timesheet')][contains(@src, 'FIN_TM_ENTRY_DYNPRO_MSTR')] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and also cross check if that `<iframe>` is is a _child iframe_ which is within another parent `<iframe>`

Comment: Still Expected condition failed.waiting for frame error. There no parent <iframe> but the <iframe> is defined inside a body tag  <body tabindex="-1" id="nwbc" onload="pro54_init();pro54_load_iframe();pro54_init_h_tabindex();" class="html_close" onunload="pro54_clean_up();pro54_send_XHR_terminator();">